# How to catch a plsql output value

Tags: oracle, plsql, vb6

I'm new to VB and I was wondering how to catch an output value from an oracle command.

I got this code:

```
Dim paramRet
Dim output

Sub function()

sql = "DECLARE
 variable := VARCHAR(10);

 variable := 'TEST';

BEGIN
 :=output := variable;
END; "

   Connect2Oracle    

    ExecuteSQLStatement sql  

    Set paramRet = adoCmd.CreateParameter("output",202,2,"20")
    adoCmd.Parameters.Append paramRet  

//print paramRet..
```

but I don't get any return value for my paramRet. What am I missing?

EDIT: noticed that I've no reference to my query "sql" in CreateParameter is my observation  correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing several things. First and foremost, anonymous procedures don't have any return value or out parameter. So, to get a return value you need to create a function in the Oracle database.

Example:

PL/SQL:

```
Function Add5 (num in number) RETURN NUMBER IS
   Begin
   Return (num + 5);
End Add5;
```

VB:

```
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim InputParam As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim ReturnParam As New ADODB.Parameter

cmd.ActiveConnection = myconnection
cmd.CommandText = "Add5"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
Set InputParam = cmd.CreateParameter("Prm1", adSmallInt, adParamInput, , 30)

'Using adParamOutPut instead of adParamReturnValue will result in the 
'following error:
'ORA-24334 - no descriptor for this position
'Set Prm2 = cmd.CreateParameter("Prm2", adSmallInt, adParamOutput) ' This is how you would use an out parameter
Set ReturnParam = cmd.CreateParameter("Prm2", adSmallInt, adParamReturnValue)

'You will also get the ORA-24334 error if you don't Append the parameters
'in the correct order. Make sure to bind the Returning parameter first.
cmd.Parameters.Append ReturnParam
cmd.Parameters.Append InputParam

cmd.Execute
MsgBox "Input Value = " & cmd.Parameters(1)
MsgBox "Return Value = " & cmd.Parameters(0)
```

[Example from Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3ap11_question_id:498045385849)